# Flink HA JobManager cluster cannot elect a leader

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink

I'm trying to deploy Apache Flink 1.6 on kubernetes. With following the tutorial at [job manager high availabilty](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/ops/jobmanager_high_availability.html)
page. I already have a working Zookeeper 3.10 cluster from its logs I can see that it's healthy and doesn't configured to Kerberos or SASL.All ACL rules are let's every client to write and read znodes. When I start the cluster everything works as expected every JobManager and TaskManager pods are successfully getting into Running state and I can see the connected TaskManager instances from the master JobManager's web-ui. But when I delete the master JobManager's pod, the other JobManager pod's cannot elect a leader with following error message on any JobManager-UI in the cluster.

```
{
  "errors": [
    "Service temporarily unavailable due to an ongoing leader election. Please refresh."
  ]
}
```

Even if I restart this page nothing changes. It stucks at this error message.
My suspicion is, the problem is related with `high-availability.storageDir` option. I already have a working (tested with [CloudExplorer](https://github.com/rusher81572/cloudExplorer))  [minio](https://www.minio.io/) s3 deployment to my k8s cluster. But flink **cannot** write anything to the s3 server. Here you can find every config from [github-gist](https://gist.github.com/rfum/6891bb390ce031da9e3086a27d1499a5).

Answer (score 0):

According to the logs it looks as if the `TaskManager` cannot connect to the new leader. I assume that this is the same for the web ui. The logs say that it tries to connect to `flink-job-manager-0.flink-job-svc.flink.svc.cluster.local/10.244.3.166:44013`. I cannot say from the logs whether `flink-job-manager-1` binds to this IP. But my suspicion is that the headless service might return multiple IPs and Flink picks the wrong/old one. Could you log into the `flink-job-manager-1` pod and check what its IP address is?

I think you should be able to resolve this problem by defining for each `JobManager` a dedicated service or if you use the pod hostname instead.

Comment: AFAIK the headless service cannot return multiple pod ip address. you can check that from link. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services. I still think the issue is about s3 backend for storing the recovery metadata (`high-availability.storageDir`). Do you exactly know what does this metadata's content?

Comment: How fast does the DNS entry get updated? I don't see a problem with `high-availability.storageDir`. To me it looks like a connection problem between the pods, e.g. a wrong IP address.

Comment: Does any documentation exists about, how this leader election process is happening?  I may find the problem, if i know the whole process.

Comment: I think there is no detailed information about this. But it works the following: Flink uses the Curator `LeaderLatch` to select a leader. The leader will then write its address to `ZooKeeper` from where the `ZooKeeperLeaderRetrievalServices` find the address. This seems to work. However, I suspect since all `Dispatchers` have the same DNS, that the Kubernetes DNS entry has not been updated to point to the new IP address. Therefore I would suggest to try out whether it works if you use the pod DNS name or define a service per `Dispatcher`.